# Setup Terraform stackdriver alerts based on GCP bucket

Tags: google-cloud-stackdriver, terraform-provider-gcp, google-cloud-monitoring

I am trying to setup stack driver alerting policies thru terraform, and based on cloud storage bucket conditions.
So whenever there is a file in the GCP bucket, It should trigger a mail notification to our mails (Not using SendGrind). 
For now, I got this mail notification working thru GCP console via stack-driver. But I am trying to incorporate it using terraform.
Any guidance is really appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Figured out thru terraform import google monitoring policies. Incorporated all thru terraform and managed to hook up notifications sent thru stackdriver over bucket changes as well.